# Can't install package caret on RHEL 7.x

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to use Feature Selection with the Caret R Package, but I can't install it on my linux machine. I've tried various things, I've also used `dependencies=TRUE` inside `install.packages` with no results. Any help?

Here is the log:

```
    Warning: dependency 'car' is not available
    trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/caret_6.0-52.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3665293 bytes (3.5 Mb)
    opened URL
    ==================================================
    downloaded 3.5 Mb

    ERROR: dependency 'car' is not available for package 'caret'
    * removing '/usr/lib64/R/library/caret'

    The downloaded source packages are in
            '/tmp/RtmpKfvgyR/downloaded_packages'
    Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
    Making 'packages.html' ... done
    Warning message:
    In install.packages("caret") :
      installation of package âcaretâ had non-zero exit status
    > 
    > sessionInfo()
    R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
    Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

    locale:
     [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
     [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
     [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
     [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
     [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
    [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

**UPDATE:**
I've upgraded R to version 3.2.1 and now I can install caret package. Just `sudo yum install R` and it was solved.

Comment: sudo apt-get install ucommon-utils ?

Comment: did you mean `sudo yum install ucommon-utils` ? It doesn't work.